# Convert Oct to text from String in javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I try to convert oct value to char from my string i perform this logic but it does not return the right value which I want.

```
    decodeUnicodeChar(obj1) {
      if (obj1 == null || obj1 == undefined)
        return "";
      var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
      var r3 = /\\([\d\w]{3})/gi;
      obj1 = obj1.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16));
      }).replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
      obj1 = unescape(obj1) ? unescape(obj1) : decodeURIComponent(obj1);
    console.log(obj1);
     document.write(obj1);
  }
  
  decodeUnicodeChar("Hello \361o")
```

Current Output:-
Hello \361o

Needed Output:- Hello ño

Comment: If you have an "oct value", why do you use base 16?? Also, why does the needed output not have *anything* for the `361 o` part? Why do you escape the `3` with a backslash in the string literal? It will not have any effect. It is the same string as `Hello 361o`. You should escape the backslash if you need a literal backslash in your string. What is `r3` for? You never use it... And `r` expects a `u` in your string, which is not there. So many issues here...

Comment: sorry that I added wrong output now output like now it is seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- You have an "oct value", but only use base 16 in `parseInt`. You would need to use base 8 for parsing octal numbers.
- There is no backslash in your input string. `"\3"` is exactly the same as `"3"`, because you are actually escaping the "3" (which is not necessary). You need to escape the backslash if you want a literal backslash: `"\\"`.
- Although you created the regular expression for matching octal numbers in your input (as `r3`), you never use that regular expression.

Other remarks:

- When the input argument is null, you *return* a string, but in the other case your function does not return anything. It just outputs it. You should return the string.
- If the argument is `undefined` then `== null` will be `true` also, so there is no need for the `||` expression in the `if` condition.
- Don't use `document.write`. It is almost always better to assign to the `innerHTML` property of a DOM element.
- Don't name your variable `obj1` when in fact it is expected to have a string data type.

```js
function decodeUnicodeChar(str) {
  if (str == null) return ""; // no need extra test on undefined
  var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
  var r3 = /\\([\d\w]{3})/gi;
  str = str.replace(r, (match, grp) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)))
           .replace(r3, (match, grp) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 8)))
           .replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
  return decodeURIComponent(str); // return it
}

console.log(decodeUnicodeChar("Hello \\361o")); // escape backslash
```

Finally, I would suggest using JSON formatted strings, which allows for encoding unicode characters. And then you only have to call `JSON.parse`.